# Assigning DisplayMember of a combo box with a value from a Tuple within a list of Tuple - C#

Tags: c#, combobox, tuples

I have a combo box on a windows form that I am trying to populate with a list of clients.  I have a List of Tuple with three values  (`var clients = new List<Tuple<int, string, string>>();`)  I am getting data from a SQL call returning a `clientID`, `clientName`, and `path`.

The issue I am having is, my combo box is displaying `(1, companyName, c:\Path)` which is the first value of my list, but what I really want to display is the `companyName` (Item2 in the tuple) and not the other data.

If my `clients` variable was just a Tuple instead of a list of Tuple I would be able to do this:

```
comboBoxClients.DisplayMember = clients.Item2;
comboBoxClients.ValueMember = clients.Item1
```

Here is the code I tried to use which didn't work:

```
var clients = new List<Tuple<int, string, string>>();
clients = GetClients();
comboBoxClient.DataSource = clients;
comboBoxClient.DisplayMember = clients[0].Item2;
```

Is there a way I can set the `DisplayMember` to the second item of my tuple in the list? Is there something else I should be using instead of a tuple?  Any help with this is appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try setting `comboBoxClient.DisplayMember = "Item2";`

`DisplayMember` should be a string declaring the name of the property to be diplayed. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Handling of `ValueMember` is the same.

Comment: Nevermind, its fine. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Excellent.  Thank you.  That makes a lot of sense.  I was attempting to set the "value" as the displayMember/valueMember and not the name of the Item column in the Tuple.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Sorry, didn't see that you already inserted the link when I edited my post.

Comment: @JohnJanssen You're welcome. Good luck with the C# 'Reflection' technology. ;-)